# Duplicate result in join query

Tags: mysql, join

Here is my tables:

`Book (id ,title ,author ,isbn ,cost)`

`Orders(orderID ,orderDate ,user(manyToOne) ,orderItems(oneToMany))`

`OrderItem(id ,book(ManyToOne) ,quantity ,totalPrice)`

this is the query:

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

But, the result should had just `2 rows`, contain just `orderId 1 and 2` not 4 rows.

Comment: I didn't understood what is duplicated, from your join you have two orders, each one have the same two books, giving you the 4 results. What you have making the selects on those two tables separately?

Comment: on condition mission for orderitem table

Comment: There is no co-relation between these two *inner join* tables namely `orders` and `orderitem`. It will result in producing a cartesian  product by means of a *cross join*. You need `...FROM orders JOIN orderitem ON orders.orderID = orderitem.id JOIN book ON book.id = orderitem.book_id` instead (aliases are only needed, if column names conflict. `book_id` is not listed in the `OrderItem` table, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining on order correctly. It looks like it is doing a cross join. See the correct sql below.

```
select
  *
from
  orders o

  inner join orderitem oi on
    oi.orderID = o.orderID -- note the additional join here

  inner join book b on
    b.id = oi.book_id
```

You can see on the join I have joined orders onto orderitem correctly. You might need to change the id since I am not sure if it should be order_id, orderID or just ID. Don't know your schema.